# Call view controller method from custom class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom class and a view controller.

My custom class:

```
class ChatManager:NSObject {

    func messageArrived() {
         //When Message arrives I am handling it from here
         //I need something like that: Viewcontroller.updateTable()
    }
}
```

When message arrives from internet I need to update tableview in view controller. So I mean I have to call a view controller method from `messageArrived` method. How can I do this ?

Comment: You should take a look at `delegation`, make your viewController a ChatManagerDelegate, assign it and then send the update message to said delegate.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: Not in swift, no :/ But just google `swift delegate pattern`

Comment: Is that correct : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html ?

Comment: yes, reading the apple docs is a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using delegate:

declare the delegate before your chat manager class

```
protocol ChatManagerDelegate {
    func manageMessage()
}
```

when the message arrived, call the delegate method to handle it.

```
class ChatManager: NSObject {

    var delegate: ChatManagerDelegate?

    func messageArrived() {
        self.delegate!.manageMessage()
    }
}
```

in your view controller, remember to set the delegate of the chat manager to self.

```
class ViewController: ChatManagerDelegate {
    var manager = ChatManager()
    manager.delegate = self

    func manageMessage() {
        self.updateTable()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, i can't call var manager = ChatManager() because actually I have three view controllers. I have to call like this: var manager=ChatManager.sharedInstance and If call, ı am getting expected declaration error for manager.delegate=self

Comment: does it help if you call `ChatManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad` method of your ViewController?

Comment: if you want more than one controllers to handle the message arrived, notification center would be a better choice, I guess.

Comment: did you try something like `class FirstViewController: ChatManagerDelegate`?

Comment: ok, that was my fault. It is working well except one problem. My view controller is a tab so if user not presses to tab view controller is not loading.(viewDidLoad method is not calling) and if user not presses to tab my app is crashing with this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value what should i do for this ?

Comment: then put the statement inside `viewWillAppear`, hope it works.

Comment: are you using UITabController? I just tried a small project and found it works even though I didn't touch the tab

Comment: Yes I am using UITabController

Comment: Where did you put the statement ? I mean which method

Answer (score 1):

This would be a possible implementation:

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,ChatManagerDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myChatManager = ChatManager()
      myChatManager.delegate = self
  }


  func messageDidArrive() {
    // Do Things here.
  }
}
```

Chatmanager:

```
class ChatManager:NSObject {
  var delegate:ChatManagerDelegate?

  func messageArrived() {
    //When Message arrives I am handling it from here
    //I need something like that: Viewcontroller.updateTable()
  }
}
```

Delegate-Protocol:

```
protocol ChatManagerDelegate{
  func messageDidArrive()
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you look my comment in above answer ?

Comment: Use static variable to realize your singleton: `static let sharedInstance = ChatManager()`
Then you can call  `let myChatManager = ChatManager.sharedInstance
    myChatManager.delegate = self`

Comment: And make sure you inherit the protocol in your ViewController! `class ViewController: UIViewController,ChatManagerDelegate {`